# ASP.NET MVC UpdateModel is not working (with Devexpress)

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, entity-framework-4, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I create a view, entity model and Devexpress Grid extension.
Devexpress has self generate a code. But UpdateModal function is not working on controller function in class.
throw a "The model of type 'Models.Birim' could not be updated." error text.

my codes:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult MagazaGridPartialUpdate([ModelBinder(typeof(DevExpressEditorsBinder))] Models.Birim item)
        {
            var model = db.Birim;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var modelItem = model.FirstOrDefault(it => it.id == item.id);
                    if (modelItem != null)
                    {

                        this.UpdateModel(modelItem);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewData["EditError"] = e.Message;
                }
            }
            else
                ViewData["EditError"] = "Please, correct all errors.";
            return PartialView("_MagazaGridPartial", model.ToList());
        }
```

can it work on my work idea?

Comment: Hi, I searching this solution of issue for 24 hours. But i find the solution. 
Only works with Devexpress

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T204240/gridview-the-model-of-type-webapplication1-usuario-could-not-be-updated

add in Application_Start()
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new DevExpressEditorsBinder();

Comment: You should rather post your comment as answer and accept the answer.

Comment: How can I check as completed my post :D

Comment: I see you don't have permissions to do so. I will post your comment as answer then and you can accept it. OK?

Comment: Okay, I am waiing for you

Comment: I've posted an answer based on the forum link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As orçun already pointed out, the DevExpress support has provided the necessary steps in the DevExpress forum.

Quote from [DevExpress forum](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T204240):

> So that the post data of our controls is applied properly, our
>   DevExpressEditorsBinder should be used. The UpdateModel method does
>   not use a binder specified in the ModelBinder attribute of an action
>   method. It's necessary to specify it as the default binder.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new DevExpressEditorsBinder();
}
```

> If you don't want this, you can get new values from the "item"
>   parameter of the GridViewPartialUpdate action method:

```
modelItem.LoginUsuario = item.LoginUsuario;
modelItem.Nome = item.Nome;
modelItem.Email = item.Email;
modelItem.Ativo = item.Ativo;
```